# Dynamically create function name and execute them

Tags: node.js

In nodejs 8, I try to insert 10 records int mongodb

```
// create company
await mylib.defaultCompany1SavePromise();
await mylib.defaultCompany2SavePromise();
await mylib.defaultCompany3SavePromise();
await mylib.defaultCompany4SavePromise();
await mylib.defaultCompany5SavePromise();
await mylib.defaultCompany6SavePromise();
await mylib.defaultCompany7SavePromise();
await mylib.defaultCompany8SavePromise();
await mylib.defaultCompany9SavePromise();
await mylib.defaultCompany10SavePromise();
```

Is it a way to dynamically create function name and execute them?

Update 1, can I do something like this:

```
for(let index=1; index<=9; index++) {
  mylib.defaultCompany{index}SavePromise();
}
```

Comment: Why are you using separate functions for each one?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Really not clear what you are asking here. Do you possibly mean "use a different collection?" or "use different criteria?" or what exactly are you asking?

Comment: see update 1 above.

Comment: @kenpeter Still no idea what you mean here. What does this have to do with MongoDB? Also see the `@` thingy in the comment. That's how you direct a message and someone actually sees it. Rather than me having to wander back and happen to see your update 4 hours later.

Comment: Nope. So how about actually explaining yourself rather than meaningless chatter? We're waiting? What are you asking? What does it have to do with MongoDB?

Comment: @NeilLunn, I had removed the mongodb tag. I will ask another question that really related to mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

Create and execute functions in one loop

```
for (let index = 1; index <= 9; index++) {
    const fnName = 'defaultCompany' + index + 'SavePromise';
    // create function
    mylib[fnName] = function () {
        // function body    
    };
    // run function
    mylib[fnName]();
}
```

or you can execute those functions in another loop.

But in my opinion it's better to pass `index` into function and modify it's behavior based on `index`